# What Does ({}); Mean in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, scope

AFAIK `{}` defines a new scope, so what does this define?

```
({});
```

The compiler compiles this program well:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::string name;
  std::cout << "What is your name? ";
  {
     ({}); 
  }
  getline (std::cin, name);
  std::cout << "Hello, " << name << "!\n";
}
```

When i replace `({});` with `();` the complier fails to compile the program.

Why does `({});` work well, but `();` does not?

I have tested the program on cpp.sh. It compiles fine.

Comment: Looks like a compiler extension to me. GCC with `-pednatic-errors` says `error: ISO C++ forbids braced-groups within expressions [-Wpedantic]`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat i have tested the program on http://cpp.sh/. it compiles fine

Comment: GCC has some non-standard extensions enabled by default. `-pedantic-errors` disables them. `-pedantic` (or `-Wpedantic`) makes GCC generate warnings when they're used. Cpp.sh has a checkbox to enable the second one.

Comment: Specifically, it's the "statement expression" extension in GCC - you can Google it.

Comment: "AFAIK {} defines a new scope" that is a wrong statement, there are at least three different contexts in which curly braces  are used

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`({});` is not part of standard C++. As correctly said by @HolyBlackCat this is compiler extension. Use `-pedantic-errors` to disable compiler extensions.

See live demo [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a4fc0a821ac88a85) when compiled on `g++`

See live demo [here](http://rextester.com/MZQYDQ7326) when compiled on `vc++`.

Comment: So VC is more in line than GCC standard-wise when it comes to this. Well, that's a first.

Comment: @GillBates: Why is it a first? See variable-length arrays for a more common example of a GCC compiler extension which is enabled by default. Sadly, both GCC and VC need to be explicitly told to be ISO-compliant (or try to be as compliant as possible). You cannot just run `g++ program.cpp` or `cl.exe program.cpp` and expect the compiler to behave correctly.

Comment: @Christian - At least for Microsoft the default setting has always been *"Compile as much code as possible, so the customers won't call the product support"*. Cost-benefit analysis.  :-)

Comment: @BoPersson: Then the counter strategy should be to call product support every time that non-compliant code is compiled :)

Comment: @Bo Persson in fact they primarily support their _own_ codebase, that's why MS fanatically supports some C features that considered UB in C++, for example. Or why it supports open-ended structures (structures that end with array of undefined size) - because entire internal API of Windows is built on those structures. PS.(OT) <looks up> Are people competing in how funnier\clever they nicknames are here (And my name isn't after programming language, I've learned about it few months ago)?